# Жизненный цикл программы в iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

Всем привет)
Интересует в деталях сам жизненый цикл приложение, не где не могу найти материал на данную тему (

Думаю точный ответ будет выглядеть примерно так:
**Жизненный цикл программы в iOS**

```
      1. application:didFinishLaunchingwithOptions
      2. applicationWillResignActive
      3. applicationDidBecomeActive
      4. applicationWillEnterBackground
      5. applicationWillEnterForeground
      6. applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по-моему [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129557/) очень хорошо описан жизненный цикл UIViewController'a. Если вы это имели ввиду, конечно.
Коротко это выглядит примерно так:
Создание

```
init
initWithNibName:
```

Создание view

```
(BOOL)isViewLoaded
loadView
viewDidLoad
(UIView*) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
(UIView*) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
```

Обработка изменения состояния view

```
viewDidLoad
viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
viewDidUnload
```

Обработка memory warning

```
didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

Уничтожение

```
viewDidUnload
dealloc
```

Answer (score 1):

[гугл](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=ios+app+lifecycle&aq=f&oq=ios+app+lifecycle&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j0l3j62.1665j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[ютуб](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ios+app+lifecycle&oq=ios+app+lifecyc&gs_l=youtube.3.0.33i21.701.10545.0.12267.32.23.8.1.1.0.99.1269.23.23.0...0.0...1ac.1.We8AiUGU_QA)

а где ищете что не  можете найти?

Comment: первый по ссылке в гугле кстати -  developer.apple.com. Рекомендую начать оттуда